# Find the harmonic conjugate of $u(x,y)=x^3+ax^2y+bxy^2+2y^3$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find the harmonic conjugate of $u(x,y)=x^3+ax^2y+bxy^2+2y^3$. Using the C-R equations $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$, I have found that $v(x,y)=\frac{b}{3}y^3-\frac{a}{3}x^3-bx^2y-6xy^2+c$.

The $v$ that I've calculated satisfies the second equation in C-R, but not the first one. So it is not correct. But I've repeated the calculations 4-5 times now, each time getting the same conclusion. There is an error in it. Can anyone help me to find the error? I am unable to see it. Please help.

Comment: Is your function $u$ harmonic ($\Delta u = 0$) for all $a$ and $b$?

Comment: What that has to do with $v$?

Comment: $(v_y)_x = (v_x)_y$ implies $(u_x)_x = (-u_y)_y$, hence $\Delta u = u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$.

Comment: Ok $u$ is not harmonic so it means that I cannot find the harmonic conjugate right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 6x + 2ay + 2bx + 12y$, we see that $u(x,y)$ is harmonic only when $a = -6$ and $b = -3$.

Plugging in these values to the $v(x,y)$ that you (correctly) calculated, you will see that $u$ and $v$ indeed satisfy the CR equations.